# Dynamic Menu in C# ASP.Net MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

#### Explaining

I'm trying to do a dynamic menu, loading items from database.
I need 3 levels max inside the menu, like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>Peoples
      <ul>
         <li>Employee
            <ul>
              <li>Create</li>
              <li>List</li>
              <li>Edit</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Training</li>
         <li>Material Requisition</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul
```

## Now, this is how i'm doing today, but without sucess:

The partial view "TopBar.cshtml" shows in every page, and it's called inside "_Layout.cshtml" like this:

#### _Layout.cshtml

```
<body>
    @Html.Partial("TopBar")
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        (...)
```

and the "**TopBar.cshtml**" shows the data using the code below

```
@model IEnumerable<SIGO.Models.TopMenu>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="SigoLogo" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("")'">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" title="Início">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/Wlogo.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @if (Model != null){
                    foreach(var item in Model.Where(p => p.Nivel == 0)) {
                        if (Model.Where(s1 => s1.Parent == item.TopMenuID) != null) {
                            <li>@item.Descricao
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach (var sub1 in Model.Where(s1 => s1.Parent == item.TopMenuID)) {
                                        if (Model.Where(s2 => s2.Parent == sub1.TopMenuID) != null) {
                                            <li>@sub1.Descricao
                                                <ul>
                                                    @foreach (var sub2 in Model.Where(s2 => s2.Parent == sub1.TopMenuID)) {
                                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(sub2.Descricao,sub2.Action,sub2.Controller)</li>
                                                    }
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        }else{
                                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(sub1.Descricao,sub1.Action,sub1.Controller)</li>
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        }else{
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Descricao,item.Action,item.Controller)</li>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the "**TopMenu**" class

```
    public class TopMenuItem {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }             //Iterator
            public int Parent { get; set; }         //TopMenuItem parent id
            public bool Group { get; set; }         //If this have another item below
            public string Descricao { get; set; }   //Text to show
            public string Action { get; set; }      //Action to Go
            public string Controller { get; set; }  //Controller to Go
    }
```

All this result in blank list, like a clean database.
But, when i call an action List e.g. a conflict occurs, because booth Views ("List.cshtml" and "TopBar.cshtml") starts with:

```
@model IEnumerable<SIGO.Models.Employee>
```

or

```
@model IEnumerable<SIGO.Models.TopMenu>
```

P.S.: I don't use any controller to process the data to TopMenu.

## Questions

- How can i do this TopMenu?
- Do you have another solution?

Thanks! Sorry for any mistake in translation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## This is the solution reached with the answers above

*Thanks for all*

### Class: TopMenu.cs

```
    public class TopMenu {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }             //Iterator
        public int Parent { get; set; }         //TopMenuItem parent id
        public bool Group { get; set; }         //If this have another item below
        public string Descricao { get; set; }   //Text to show
        public string Action { get; set; }      //Action to Go
        public string Controller { get; set; }  //Controller to Go
    }
```

### Context: SigoContext.cs

```
    public class SigoContext : DbContext {
        public SigoContext() : base("SigoMain") {}
            public DbSet<TopMenu> TopMenu{ get; set; }
        }
    }
```

### Controller: SigoController.cs

```
    public class SystemController : Controller {
        private SigoContext db = new SigoContext();

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult TopMenu() {
            return PartialView("TopBar",db.TopMenu);
        }
    }
```

### Layout: _Layout.cshtml

```
...
<body>
    @{Html.RenderAction("TopMenu", "System");}
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
...
```

### Partial View: TopMenu.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<SIGO.Models.TopMenu>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="SigoLogo">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" title="Início">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/Wlogo.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @if (Model != null){
                        foreach(var item in Model.Where(p => p.Parent == 0)) {
                            if (Model.Where(s1 => s1.Parent == item.Id) != null) {
                                <li>@item.Descricao
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach (var sub1 in Model.Where(s1 => s1.Parent == item.Id)) {
                                            if (Model.Where(s2 => s2.Parent == sub1.Id) != null) {
                                                <li>@sub1.Descricao
                                                    <ul>
                                                        @foreach (var sub2 in Model.Where(s2 => s2.Parent == sub1.Id)) {
                                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(sub2.Descricao,sub2.Action,sub2.Controller)</li>
                                                        }
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            }else{
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink(sub1.Descricao,sub1.Action,sub1.Controller)</li>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            }else{
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Descricao,item.Action,item.Controller)</li>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank guys!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the model to the partial view. On the contrary, this condition will always be  false and nothing will be rendered:

```
@if (Model != null)
```

So, you'd need to render the view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("TopBar", model)
```

In your case, as this code is in the layout view, you have no way to get the `model`.

The only reasonable way to implement this is to create a controller to provide the model. If you do so, instead of using `Partial` you should use `Action` or `RenderAction` ([MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions(v=vs.118).aspx)). I.e. implement it like this:

- create a `MenuController` with a `Menu` action that returns a `PartialView` which renders the menu. Create the model inside this action, and use `return Partial("Menu",model)`, where `"Menu"` refers to a `"Menu.cshtml"` view, and model has the data required to render this view. This action will render the menu.
- use `Html.RenderAction("Menu","Menu")` to render the menu inside the layout. The first `"Menu"` parameter refers to the action name, and the second refers to the controller.

Comment: Thank u! Creating the MenuController and calling the TopMenu action inside the "_Layout.cshtml" solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate controller/action method to construct your menu and call it using `@Html.Action()`.  For example

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
  [ChildActionOnly]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    // Build your menu model;
    return PartialView(model);
  }
}
```

Then in your layout

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Menu")
```

Comment: Thanks! just one more detail:
1) inside layout, i've used "@{Html.RenderAction("TopMenu", "System");}" and works.
2) inside controller, i used out of action: "private SigoContext db = new SigoContext();" , and inside action: "return PartialView("TopBar",db.TopMenu);"

Comment: Point 1): They both do the essentially the same thing. The difference is that `@Html.RenderAction()` renders the result directly to the Response (which is more efficient if the action returns a large amount of HTML) whereas `@Html.Action()` returns a string with the result. Point 2): I don't understand what your asking - is there a problem?

Comment: It isn't a problem. I just say how i've reached the solution with your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.
I am using this and it works.

VIEW CODE

```
<ul id="nav">
        @foreach (var p in Model.Where(a => a.MENU_MASTER.PARENT_ID == 0))
        {

            if (Model.Where(a => a.MENU_MASTER.PARENT_ID == p.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_ID).Any())
            {
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">@p.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_NAME</a>
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var c in Model.Where(g => (g.MENU_MASTER.PARENT_ID == p.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_ID)))
                    {
                        if (Model.Where(a => a.MENU_MASTER.PARENT_ID == c.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_ID).Any())
                        {
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>@c.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_NAME</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach (var d in Model.Where(a => a.MENU_MASTER.PARENT_ID == c.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_ID))
                                {
                                    <li><a  href="@Url.Action(@d.MENU_MASTER.ACTION_NAME, @d.MENU_MASTER.CONTROLLER_NAME)">
                                        <span>@d.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_NAME</span></a> </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        }
                        else
                        {
                        <li><a  href="@Url.Action(@c.MENU_MASTER.ACTION_NAME, @c.MENU_MASTER.CONTROLLER_NAME)">
                            <span>@c.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_NAME</span></a> </li>  
                        }

                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
            }
            else
            {
            <li><a class="hsubs" href="#">@p.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_NAME</a></li>
            }

        }
    </ul>
```

Controller code

```
 public ActionResult menu()
        {
            List<PartialClass> Q = new List<PartialClass>();
            var query = ctx.MENU_MASTER.Select(a => new { a.ACTION_NAME, a.CONTROLLER_NAME, a.OBJECT_ID, a.OBJECT_NAME, a.PARENT_ID });
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                PartialClass cs = new PartialClass();
                cs.MENU_MASTER.ACTION_NAME = item.ACTION_NAME;
                cs.MENU_MASTER.CONTROLLER_NAME = item.CONTROLLER_NAME;
                cs.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_ID = item.OBJECT_ID;
                cs.MENU_MASTER.OBJECT_NAME = item.OBJECT_NAME;
                cs.MENU_MASTER.PARENT_ID = item.PARENT_ID;
                Q.Add(cs);
            }

            return View(Q);
        }
```

Model class

```
public class MENU_MASTER
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal OBJECT_ID { get; set; }
        public string OBJECT_NAME { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> OBJECT_TYPE { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MENU_GROUP")]
        public Nullable<decimal> GROUP_ID { get; set; }
        public string LINK_NAME { get; set; }
        public string IMAGE_PATH { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ORDER_OF_APEARANCE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> CREATED_BY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATED_ON { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> MODIFIED_BY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> MODIFIED_ON { get; set; }
        public string CONTROLLER_NAME { get; set; }
        public string ACTION_NAME { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MODULE_MASTER")]
        public Nullable<decimal> MODULE_ID { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PARENT_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual MENU_GROUP MENU_GROUP { get; set; }
        public virtual MODULE_MASTER MODULE_MASTER { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Pawan! You helped me in another problem.